# Using NOW() function to generate a timestamp and stopping it from updating

Tags: function, google-sheets, time, timestamp

I'm having a new issue lately happened while I was using this formula for the last 5 months and there was no issue with the time stamp that generated, lately every time I open the sheet the last date entered only changed which is a bit weird as the morning date entered was not

the formula is : ={"TIMESTAMP";ARRAYFORMULA(IFS(C2:C="","",A2:A="",NOW(),TRUE,A2:A))} i did add a sheet sample https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n_YnB00OR6Rfa1UcdLKb9jxyeEZw2SUtUacfg3obJ50/edit#gid=0 with note how the timestamp was changing while there is no change in column C

looking forwards to your kind support.

Thanks

Comment: not possible. you will need a timestamp script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get a permanent timestamp with a spreadsheet formula, not even with a custom function, because formula results are refreshed from time to time. When that happens, the formula gets recalculated and the original timestamp is lost.

The easiest way to insert a timestamp in a cell is to press `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + ;` (on a Mac, press `⌘ + ⌥ + Shift + ;`). See the [keyboard shortcuts](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&p=spreadsheets_shortcuts&answer=181110) help page.

As you must be aware, many people use simple `onEdit(e)` triggers to create static timestamps. Search this forum for many examples, or take a look at the [timestampMultipleColumns_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/28719648?msgid=28825318) script.

Comment: Hi, i did use it before and it works perfectly you could refer to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bU0z_6gxI98  and I never had an issue, it only start few days ago am trying to avoid using onEdit cause its slow and not fast when there is multiple sheets

Comment: You cannot get a _permanent_ timestamp with a spreadsheet formula. Iterative calculation does not change that, and using it is a bad idea because of performance issues and potential inconsistencies in formula results.

Comment: understand your kind advice, would explain how this code work pls if possible: const oSet = e.range.offset(0,(e.range.columnStart === 3 ? -2 : 1)); Thanks

Comment: appreciate your advice